# AspNet Core Identity - cookie not getting set in production

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET Core 2 web app and I want to use ASP.NET Identity to authenticate my users. On .NET Core 1.x, my code was working fine.

I migrated to .NET Core 2, and authentication works when running locally in Visual Studio. But when I deploy to a live environment, authentication stops working: **the authentication cookie isn't being set in production.**

My Startup.cs code looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddIdentity<AppUser, RavenDB.IdentityRole>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 

   ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   ...

   app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

To sign in, my code looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(...)
{
   var user = ...; // Load the User from the database.
   await this.signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);

   ...
}
```

This code works locally: the ASP.NET Identity auth cookie is set. However, when I deploy this to production enviro in Azure, the cookie never gets set.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved the problem. It boiled down to HTTPS: it appears that signInManager.SignInAsync(...) sets a cookie that is HTTPS-only. I was publishing to a non-HTTPS site initially for testing.

Once I published to an HTTPS site, the cookie started working again.

The reason it was working locally was that I was running in HTTPS locally.

Comment: Hi @Judah I've the same problem, but I'm using `PasswordSignInAsync` and persistent can be false (depends of user choice), also my deploy is https, any idea?

Comment: it has anything to do with apps (IS and client) being on different domains?

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem with Chrome 60+. Cookie did not want to set on HTTP site or even HTTPS and Cordova.
`options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;`
https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie.md
Changing from default value (Lax) to None fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. In the startup.cs file, I had to change

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
     Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
});
```

to

```
 app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
 {
     Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
 });
```

This allowed cookie authentication to work on both http and https.