# AspNet Core Identity, how set options.Cookie.SameSite?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In the latest templates and libraries used httpsonly flag. How can I turn it off?

This same question is outdated and it did not have full configuration sample:

[AspNet Core Identity - cookie not getting set in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059955/aspnet-core-identity-cookie-not-getting-set-in-production)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to configure the application cookie when using Identity, you can use the [`ConfigureApplicationCookie` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.configureapplicationcookie) inside your Startup’s `ConfigureServices`:

```
// add identity
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>();

// configure the application cookie
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Since Identity essentially adds cookie authentication under the hood, this is the configure action is the same thing you would normally pass to `AddCookie()` when configuring cookie authentication. It’s just that since `AddIdentity()` takes care of setting up authentication for you, the `ConfigureApplicationCookie` offers a way to adjust the cookie authentication options afterwards.

Comment: What about .Net 6 which doesn't have `startup.cs` file and it's been combined with `program.cs` file?
I'm getting this error in my console:

"migrate entirely to https to have cookies sent to same-site subresources"

Answer (score 23):

The answer by @poke did not help me set the value to `SameSiteMode.None`, atleast not in ASP.NET core 2.1.

Any value you set in configure application cookie is overridden by the `MinimumSameSitePolicy` setting of the [cookie policy middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#cookie-policy-middleware).

To prevent the override, set `MinimumSameSitePolicy` for the `UseCookiePolicy` extension as `SameSiteMode.None`.

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
   MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
});
```

Then set the actual same site value in the AddCookie extension in the `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options => options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: The accepted solution did not work for me. However, this solution did. I actually needed to set it to Strict - but this code works.

Comment: At last the answer I was looking work!

Answer (score 3):

For my case in asp.net core 3.1 two things in combination did the trick

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(opts => {
            opts.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
        });
```